# Hospedagem automática de JPG a partir de funções PHP e Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, input, file-upload

Possuo no site de um cliente uma parte onde mostra o nome do usuário logado, a unidade onde ele trabalha e a foto do usuário.

Estou querendo implementar uma função automatizada (em javascript e php) para que quando o usuário clique na foto abra automaticamente a janela de escolha de arquivos pra ele poder substituir a foto, se ele quiser.

O código em HTML dessa parte da foto e um input de file oculto:

```
<a title="Clique aqui para trocar sua foto" onclick='trocarFoto()'><img class='FotoAniversariante'
<?php echo "src='".'upload/wt_usuario/'.$_SESSION['usuario']['id'].".jpg'></a>";    ?>
<input type="file" id="imgupload" style="display:none" />
<button id="novaFoto" style="display: none"></button>
```

E a função **trocarFoto()** em javascript:

```
function trocarFoto(){
    $('#imgupload').trigger('click');
}
```

O que eu queria era que, no momento em que o novo arquivo fosse escolhido, que ele já hospedasse no diretório do meu servidor (upload/wt_usuario). Acredito que tenha que ser uma função que envolva AJAX.

Mas eu também preciso garantir que ele só aceita JPG e com dimensões de 50 por 50. Como isso é possível?

Comment: AJAX somente se você desejar que não seja mudado de página, mas poderia muito bem submeter um formulário normalmente e depois do upload retornar a página inicial. Se desejar com AJAX, veja [isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+upload+ajax). Já, para verificar o tamanho da imagem, leia [isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+dimensão+imagem).